# Sets, setts and settes

Tags: mathematics, neologisms

In the Oxford English Dictionary, [sett](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=sett) and [sette](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=sette) are listed as variants of *set*, and it appears to me, from the links, that such use is attested as from 1387.

I want to use sett and sette, in addition to set, in a work on set theory, to distinguish between various notions.

What format should an appeal to OED have, to get some support for the use of the special terms, in this case? May I just write that "sett" and "sette" are variants of "set", according to OED, or are there some qualifications I should include, beyond the inessential one that the terms "set" and "sette" were probably not used earlier in English for the mathematical notion of set?

Comment: They weren't used for mathematics. There is no "good way" to appeal to the OED when you want to use a word in a sense it never had.  They weren't used precisely. The word could mean "sect, faction, group, collection".

Comment: @TimR Confer the tags of the question. The word "good" has many meanings, and I am interested in what format such an appeal should have; I revise accordingly.

Comment: You should not attempt to appeal to the OED.   You could simply say that in Chaucer's day, centuries before modern-day attempts to normalize spelling, one could find the word **set** spelled in different ways, including **sett** and **sette**, and in my treatise I'm going to use those spellings to indicate different kinds of mathematical sets.

Comment: @TimR Many thanks - I very much appreciate your suggestion! If you state it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You could reasonably mention – when defining 3 special terms as set, sett, and sette - that your starting point is the old versions of the same word per OED. Appeal to the reader, not OED.

Comment: I'll leave it as a comment as I don't wish to appear to condone what you intend to do, since I think it would be confusing, especially in an academic conference setting where you have to discuss the topic.    Why not repurpose some modern day nouns?  Bag... Sack...Purse...Pouch...Valise?

Comment: Distinguish between which various notions? You should listen to Peter Shor, he is a mathematician.

Comment: @TimR I would of course not use such homophonous words, with different and important meanings, in a lecture. So this is for the written work. Terms as  "bag"... "sack"..."purse"..."pouch"..."valise" are not advisable as "set"-surrogates, as mathematics abound with categories, morasses, groups, and so on ...; so unintended confusion could easily arise.

Comment: @Lambie For your question on notions, see my comment to Peter Shor.

Comment: This idea is out of left field. It's essentially the same as if you decided to use "realization" and "realisation" to mean different things—the only difference is that both of those spellings are still alive and well in the present day. Almost every word in Middle English had different spellings; a few words even had *hundreds* of different spellings each, but that's not because they had hundreds of different meanings but because the orthography was not standardized (or "standardised" if you prefer).

Comment: @Laurel Ten thousand years ago, words did not have spellings.

Comment: You probably have the availability of different typefaces; shadowline and gothic styles will be sufficiently distinct from say Arial. Colour-coding is another possibility. But you obviously need to define styles.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I know, and, to a large extent, use, all sorts of tricks in LaTeX. But I think it is an esthetical virtue to only use such tricks when it is quite necessary.

Comment: Be careful, you might end up with something like the horrible situation the English have gotten themselves into with "ton" and "tonne."  If you want to have two different words for similar things, pick words that both _sound_ and _look_ different.

Comment: It is far worse to use English in non-standard and confusing ways.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Non-standard and confusing English is optimal, for poetry, and, as it seems, for discussions about style on English Language & Usage. Good mathematicians are, as Sofya Kovalevskaya pointed out, always poets at heart, and you cannot argue with theorems.

Comment: You were asking about mathematical usage. A good mathematician keeps non-standard language tidily in their non-mathematical writings. Questions on preferred styles are properly asked on Literature.SE or Writing.SE.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, I was not asking about mathematical usage. Good mathematicians have a variety of styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a math paper, there is no need to appeal to the OED for justification of new notation — people invent new words for math relatively often. For example, the word [homotopy](https://www.google.com/search?q=who+invented+the+word+homotopy&oq=who+invented+the+word+homotopy&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQIRigATIHCAIQIRigATIHCAMQIRigAdIBCDY4ODhqMGo0qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) was invented by the mathematician Oswald Veblen in 1922.

On the other hand, I really don't think it's a good idea to use *set, sett,* and *sette* for three different concepts in mathematics. Mathematicians sometimes communicate orally, not just by writing. And coining three words for similar things that are pronounced exactly the same is a really bad idea. See ["trie"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#History,_etymology,_and_pronunciation), which (despite its etymology — from re*trie*val) people have started pronouncing *try* rather than *tree* to avoid ambiguity.

The words *multiset, subset,* and *quasiset* are already mathematical terms. I would encourage you to find prefixes you can prepend to *set* that are related to their intended meanings. (And if you can't think of prefixes that are explanatory descriptions of these things, you could always call them *marmosets*, *bassets*, or *sunsets*.)

Comment: I am well aware of the prevalence of neologisms in mathematics, of course, and as I think, it is often useful to ground neologisms in historical usage. As you know, there are well established, and conflicting, theories, as that of von Neumann-Bernays-Gödel and Quine's New Foundations, which have always been considered to be theories of sets in the literature. The context is an account of the setts of NBG, and the settes of New Foundations, in the theory of sets I have developed. All setts and settes are sets, but some sets are neither setts nor settes.

Comment: But using three homonyms for related but different concepts is a ***terrible*** idea — how would you keep the audience from being confused if you were giving a lecture that included the words *set*, *sett*, and *sette*? Consider using the terms *vNBG-sets* and *Q-sets* instead.

Comment: Shor It is a part of the ideology, that all three denote sets.  Of course, as stated in a comment above, I would of course not use such homophonous words, with different and important meanings, in a lecture.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Why not just acknowledge the suggestion and take it?

Comment: @Lambie vNBG-sets and Q-sets, you mean? Stylistic problems would arise, it seems to me. In the NBG situation, for example, with substitutes for such notions as potency sett, Tarski-sett and union sett, should it be the vNBG-potency set,  vNBG-Tarski set and vNBG-union set?

Comment: I think the point is to avoid using different spellings for those sets and prepending what you need or makes sense to mathematicians. Those last three seem fine to me, but, hey, whadda I know? I am basically innumerate. :) I just read that a potency "in all its essentials is identical with those of linear space. :)

Comment: Using *sett* and *sette* in this way would not only cause problems  in oral communication, but would also create extra work for the readers of written materials in which they appear: the readers would probably need to keep flipping back to the page where the terms are introduced to remind themselves which concept is sett and which is sette. The meanings of the terms coined by adding some prefix to *set* would be easier to keep in mind as one is reading the paper.

Comment: @jsw29 In the two very short chapters related to vNBG and New Foundations, my stylistic preference is, as indicated, to use words which are maximally similar to "set". The chapter titles will have occurrences of "sett", and "sette", to facilitate for the reader. Additionally, the text will include normative definitions as "In this chapter, and the rest of the treatise where it may occur, the term "sett" will be interpreted in the same way as the term "set according to vNBG and its standard extensions."

Comment: @PeterShor

"I would encourage you to find prefixes you can prepend to set that are related to their intended meanings."

Your suggestion was good, and I   n o w  found the prefixes which I think may serve well, namely "von" and "van" after von Neumann and van Quine. The vonsets are the  sets according to the set theory NBG initiated by von Neumann, and the vansets are the sets according to Quine's set theory NF. The mentioned set theories are the ones which are the centers of my attention in this connection.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal: Very elegant solution.